# White screen on multi site front end after upgrading Expressionengine

Tags: ee2-upgrades

I have updated my system from 2.4 to 5.4 I have removed all plugins and extensions before upgrading, after upgrade the multi sites is showing a white screen in front end Knowing that the main website works perfectly, I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything that could help me , any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that might be all sorts of things. Generally it means there is a php error.
-turn on show errors in the php settings
-turn on show errors in EE
If the main site is showing but the multi sites are not then i think you should place a new version (from the 5.4 zip) of the main index.php for the satellitet sites

Comment: Thank you very much ! , I replace index.php and everything is worked prefectly.